# Cookie not showing up on localHost website

Tags: javascript, c#

I've been trying to figure out why I can't get my cookie to show on website, here's my code:

```
  public static class UpdateCookieHelper
{
    public const string COOKIE_ACCESSOR = "TurboGroup";

    public static void SetCookie(Group aModel)
    {
        HttpCookie _Cookie = new HttpCookie(COOKIE_ACCESSOR);

        if (aModel == null)
            _Cookie.Value = String.Empty;
        else
            _Cookie.Value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aModel));

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[COOKIE_ACCESSOR] == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(_Cookie);
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(_Cookie);
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
 UpdateCookieHelper.SetCookie(_Group);
```

When I run a debug, it gets the info it needs, but on website, I can't see the cookie so my getCookie() function is always null.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was the encode. No need to do it with JSON. Works now!